# How to prevent Eclipse from making stupid automatic imports?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, import

I have got several Eclipse projects opened at the same time in my Eclipse workspace. I want to let all these projects opened as I often copy/paste code from one project to another.

My problem is that when I copy/paste code, if a class does not exist in my current project, Eclipse adds an import from another project (adding the line "import com.theotherproject.ClassOfTheOtherproject" in the header) , it makes compile errors and I have to delete these imports... I have to do these deletions several times per hour... Waste of time !

How to avoid this stupid behaviour ?

Thanks !

Comment: press `ctrl+shift+o`... it will remove unnecessary imports

Comment: Try making a library/jar of the common code not cut and paste

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go into 
Window -> preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Typing

There uncheck, under `When pasting`, `Update imports`

This will not update the imports when pasting code.

Answer (score 1):

Window -> preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Save Actions -> tick Organize imports

This will automatically delete invalid and unused imports when saving.

Then, as Gopal Rao suggest, select an object that misses an import and press **<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd>** to redo needed imports.